# Update records with single request in bulk using Rest API

Tags: laravel, rest

Instead of calling multiple times of update api, is it possible to update multiple records with just one request?

Example:

Activate student access by email address.

The sample of activation's call:

```
public function activate($email, Request $request){
{
        $student= Student::findOrFail($email);
        $student->update($request->all());
        return response()->json($student, 200); 
}
```

Is it possible to call a single update API and update all the records (with the parent values too) in JSON format:

```
{
"class":"A1",
"activated_date":"2020-07-14",
"student": [
   {"email":"aaa@www.com", "birthdate":"2009-01-14"},
   {"email":"bbb@www.com", "birthdate":"2009-02-15"},
   {"email":"ccc@www.com", "birthdate":"2009-03-16"}
]
}
```

Email address is unique, Class & activation date values are to update all students on the JSON list.

I cant use PATCH method because when I found any error, I will not process the update action (i have few more validations).
(Optional) Is it possible to return the response individually as follow:

```
"Error": [
  {"email":"bbb@www.com", "message":"Record not found."},
  {"email":"ttt@www.com", "message":"Record not found."}
]
```